# ArrayList gets only one row and the ResultSet reads more than one

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a Java n-tier application for desktop and I need to populate a JComboBox. The ResultSet in DAO reads 15 rows, but when I send the ArrayList to the JComboBox this display only the last item. What is wrong?

Here the DAO:

```
public static ArrayList<AbastosOpLog> LisAbasDisp(){
      ArrayList <AbastosOpLog> abastosop = new ArrayList<>();
      Conexion conex = new Conexion();
      AbastosOpLog abasop = new AbastosOpLog(); 
      String consulta = "select abop001.abascod, abop001.abasdesc from abop001";

      try{
         Statement st = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;
         st = conex.getConnection().createStatement();
         rs = st.executeQuery(consulta);
         if(conex != null){


            while (rs.next())
               {
                  abasop.setAbas_cod(rs.getString("abascod"));
                  abasop.setAbas_desc(rs.getString("abasdesc"));
                  abastosop.add(abasop);


               }
         }
         rs.close();
         st.close();
         conex.desconectar();
      }catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("Error."+e.getMessage());
      }
```

The Logic class:

```
public class AbastosOpLog {
   private String abas_cod;
   private String abas_desc;
   //
   public String getAbas_cod() {
      return abas_cod;
   }
   public void setAbas_cod(String abas_cod) {
      this.abas_cod = abas_cod;
   }
   public String getAbas_desc() {
      return abas_desc;
   }
   public void setAbas_desc(String abas_desc) {
      this.abas_desc = abas_desc;
   }
}
```

And the view:

```
private void LlenarOpAbastos() {
   cblisopt.removeAllItems();
   ArrayList <AbastosOpLog> abastoop = AbastosOpDao.LisAbasDisp();

      for (int i = 0; i < abastoop.size(); i++) {
          cblisopt.addItem(abastoop.get(i).getAbas_cod()); // + " - " + abastoop.get(i).getAbas_desc());

      }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, the `if(conex != null){` check is unnecessary, as it can never be null there.

Comment: Learn some basics of java programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
           while (rs.next())
           {
              abasop.setAbas_cod(rs.getString("abascod"));
              abasop.setAbas_desc(rs.getString("abasdesc"));
              abastosop.add(abasop);
           }
```

You're adding the same instance over and over. Create a new instance on each iteration (removing the earlier declaration too):

```
           while (rs.next())
           {
              AbastosOpLog abasop = new AbastosOpLog(); 
              abasop.setAbas_cod(rs.getString("abascod"));
              abasop.setAbas_desc(rs.getString("abasdesc"));
              abastosop.add(abasop);
           }
```

Comment: @reymagnus, Don't forget to "accept' the answer by clicking on the checkmark, so people know the problem has been solved.